# Removing all url in textarea from variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, textarea

I need to remove all url from variable in textarea.
But it only remove the first one. Need to removed at all once the button clicked.

```js
var urlDelete = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg";

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#input').val(
    $('#input').val().replace(urlDelete, ''))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input" style="width:400px; height: 120px">
  remove all url from variable: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg 
  
  this url must be removed: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg 
  
  must not be effected: http://stackoverflow.com
  and http://google.com 
  
  again: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg


</textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
```

How the best way to make all url removed?

Thank you so much for any guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` the at particular string and then `join` the split ed array:

```
var urlDelete = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg";

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#input').val(
    $('#input').val().split().join(urlDelete);
});
```

Check this snippet

```js
var urlDelete = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg";

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#input').val(
    $('#input').val().split(urlDelete).join(""))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="input" style="width:400px; height: 120px">
  remove all url from variable: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg this url must be removed: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg must not be effected: http://stackoverflow.com
  and http://google.com again: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg


</textarea>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="remove">remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace will only replace the first occurrence of the string. To replace all the occurrence of the string, you should use a regular expression with the global search. Modify your javaxcript as shown below.

```
var urlDelete = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Google_favicon_2012.jpg";
var regularExp = new RegExp(urlDelete, 'g'); 

$('#remove').click(function() {
  $('#input').val(
    $('#input').val().replace(regularExp, ''))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `global` flag.

```
var urlDelete = /https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/a\/a0\/Google_favicon_2012.jpg/g;

$('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#input').val(
    $('#input').val().replace(urlDelete, ''))
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_global_and_ignore_with_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Textarea is also considered as an input element containing a value. You only need to do:

```
 <textarea id="input" style="width:400px; height: 200px">

 $(#input).val('');
```

Ok so want you need to do its first get the content of your textarea, whatever it does contain:

```
 var textareaContent = $('#url-textarea').val();
```

Then you can use a regex against your textareaCOntent variable, something similar to this:

```
      var newTextareaContent = textareaContent.replace((http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#], '')?
```

)

Then you just append the new content to your textarea:

```
 textareaContent.val(newTextareaContent);
```

Comment: Hi Katcha, I need to remove specific word from variable as example in snippet. Not clear all text in textarea. Thank you for your help ^^